# Applying sentiment analysis to tweets

Tags: python, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I am struggling to apply sentiment analysis to every tweet that is generated in an SQLite file. Here is the below code. I think I am not referring to the StreamListener appropriately like I should, but I really don't know how to properly implement it.

```
auth = OAuthHandler(cons_key, cons_key_sec)     
auth.set_access_token(acc_token, acc_token_sec)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["Keyword"])

api = tweepy.API(auth)
for tweet in TwitterStream:
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    print(analysis.sentiment)
```

Does my sentiment analysis need to be implement in my def on_data function?

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        saveFile = open('db.sqlite', 'a')
        saveFile.write(data)
        saveFile.write('\n')
        saveFile.close()
        return True
```

**UPDATE:**

Currently, my code only generates an extensive list of tweets (until I stop it) into an SQLite file. Here is an example of one:

```
{"created_at":"Sun Dec 02 11:43:26 +0000 2018","id":1069195333006254080,"id_str":"1069195333006254080","text":"AWPS NEWS\nTrump-Xi Meeting Highlights\nand In-Flight Remarks to Press\n -KL Anderson, 12\/2\/2018 **UPDATED\n\nLINK: https:\/\/t.co\/hcIgOFKcdr","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":708701133951377408,"id_str":"708701133951377408","name":"U(X)=0  'A.I~R.I.S'","screen_name":"UofXis0","location":null,"url":null,"description":"Began with an interest in just A.I. (Artificial Intelligence); now expanding into curiosity about R.I.S. (Robotics and Intelligent Systems).","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":12,"friends_count":87,"listed_count":3,"favourites_count":0,"statuses_count":588,"created_at":"Sat Mar 12 17:08:12 +0000 2016","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/708704673746853888\/08z1GxyX_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/708704673746853888\/08z1GxyX_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/708701133951377408\/1457803335","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/hcIgOFKcdr","expanded_url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/1640346062903605\/posts\/2195483604056512\/","display_url":"facebook.com\/16403460629036\u2026","indices":[111,134]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1543751006734"}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a SQLite file, but rather a text file with a `.sqlite` extension...?

Comment: I have made an adjustment with an example. I am new to SQLite so am beginning to wonder if I have approached it improperly.